# How do I capture the stdin/stderr from a process that I'm spawning a windows process?

Tags: windows, pipe, spawn

So, I'm trying to capture the `stdout` and `stderr` from a process that I'm spawning.

1. I create some fifos:

   ```c
    HANDLE hstdout;
    while ((hstdout = CreateNamedPipe(
        stdout_filename.c_str()
        , PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE
        , PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT | PIPE_REJECT_REMOTE_CLIENTS
        , 10
        , 4096
        , 4096
        , 0
        , &sa)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // In case the fifo is already in use, add a _ to the name and try again.
        stdout_filename += L"_";
    }
   ```

   I do the same for `stderr`.
2. Then I create the process, with all that it entails:

   ```c
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    STARTUPINFO sui = {
        sizeof(STARTUPINFO)              // size
        , 0                              // reserved
        , nullptr                        // desktop
        , nullptr                        // title
        , 0, 0, 0, 0                     // x, y, cx, cy
        , 0, 0                           // x buffer, y buffer
        , 0                              // fill attribute
        , STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK        // flags
          | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
        , false                          // show window
        , 0                              // reserved
        , 0                              // reserved
        , GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE) // stdin
        , hstdout                        // stdout
        , hstderr                        // stderr
    };

    BOOL success
        = CreateProcess(
            nullptr                      // application name
            , &cmdline[0]                // command line
            , nullptr                    // process attributes
            , nullptr                    // security attributes
            , true                       // inherit handles
            , CREATE_NO_WINDOW           // creation flags
              | INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY
            , nullptr                    // environment
            , nullptr                    // current directory
            , &sui                       // startup info
            , &pi                        // process info
        );
   ```
3. Then I wait on the handles:

   ```c
    if (success) {
        WCHAR buffer[4096];
        DWORD bytesRead;
        enum               { eStdOut, eStdErr, eProcess };
        HANDLE handles[] = { hstdout, hstderr, pi.hProcess };
        DWORD waitResult;
        bool process_terminated = false;
        do {
            waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(_countof(handles), handles, TRUE, INFINITE);
            switch (waitResult) {
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                log_fs << L"Error: Wait timed out\n";
                break;

            case WAIT_FAILED:
                log_fs << L"Error: Wait failed\n";
                break;

            case eStdOut + WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                // stdin signaled
                if (ReadFile(hstdout, buffer, _countof(buffer), &bytesRead, nullptr)) {
                    log_fs.write(buffer, bytesRead);
                    wcout.write(buffer, bytesRead);
                }
                else {
                    log_fs << "Error reading from stdout" << endl << get_error() << endl;
                }
                break;

            case eStdErr + WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                // stderr signaled
                if (ReadFile(hstderr, buffer, _countof(buffer), &bytesRead, nullptr)) {
                    log_fs.write(buffer, bytesRead);
                    wcerr.write(buffer, bytesRead);
                }
                else {
                    log_fs << "Error reading from stderr" << endl << get_error() << endl;
                }
                break;

            case eProcess + WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                // process signaled it terminated
                log_fs << L"Process terminated" << endl;
                break;

            case eStdOut  + WAIT_ABANDONED_0:
            case eStdErr  + WAIT_ABANDONED_0:
            case eProcess + WAIT_ABANDONED_0:
                // One of the handles have been abandoned.
                log_fs << L"Error: wait abandoned " << (waitResult - WAIT_ABANDONED_0)
                    << endl << get_error() << endl;
                break;

            default:
                log_fs << L"Error: Unknown " << waitResult
                    << " (" << (waitResult - WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                    << ", " << (waitResult - WAIT_ABANDONED_0) << ")"
                    << endl << get_error() << endl;
                break;
            }
        } while (waitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0 + eProcess);

        if (!GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode)) {
            log_fs << L"Error getting return code\n";
        }
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
   ```
4. I then test it with my test program:

   ```c
    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
        std::cerr << "Hello Underworld!\n";
        // std::wstring str;
        // std::wcin >> str;
    }
   ```

What happens is that without the comments, it executes to the error else in the `eStdOut + WAIT_OBJECT_0` case.  With the windows error string being "Waiting for a process to open the other end of the pipe."  It then blocks on `WaitForMultipleObjects` indefinitely.

If I were to uncomment the last two lines in my test file, my application just blocks on `WaitForMultipleObjects` indefinitely.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output?redirectedfrom=MSDN) example on MSDN you will see

- Use `CreatePipe` to create an anonymous pipe.
- Configure inheritance of the read and write end of the pipes.
- After the child process has been created they `CloseHandle` the ends of the pipes they don't need before they read/write to the pipes!

The trick of closing the write end of stdout means you can read from it until the pipe breaks. When that happens you can `WaitForSingleObject` on the process...